# Why Array(100).map((_, i) => i + 1) doesn't return [1, 2, ..., 100]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found it strange that

```
Array(100).map(function (_, i) { return i + 1; })
```

returns `[undefined, undefined, ... , undefined]` rather than `[1, 2, ..., 100]`, i. e. the mapping not happening. On the contrary, starting with an array of 100 `undefined` works ([demo](http://jsbin.com/laziduqi/1/edit?js,console)).

Does `Array(100)` returns something other than 100 `undefined` elements?

Comment: Where are you testing this? The `(v, i) => i + 1` syntax is ECMAScript 6 / "Harmony" syntax, I think, which I'm not sure if it's implemented in all current browser versions yet. Also, [`Array.prototype.map` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Show some code to provide a picture to what and where do you get this.

Comment: @Cupcake, change it to function () {} – it won't make difference. The arrow syntax currently works in Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`Array.prototype.map` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> "callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned
>   values; it is not invoked for indexes that are undefined, those which
>   have been deleted or which have never been assigned values."

The array that you create with `Array(100)` has a length of 100, but there are not items in it. An array containing 100 items that are `undefined` on the other hand has 100 items that have a value (that is the value `undefined`), so the callback will be called for each of them.

Comment: Ok, it looks like two different `undefined` here: not defined and defined with `undefined` value, right?

Comment: @Pavlo: Exactly. If you access an array item that is not set you will get the `undefined` value back, but that doesn't mean that it has the value `undefined`. The code `var v = Array(100);alert(0 in v);` will alert `false` as there is no item with index 0.